# ¿Mover posición de elementos de array asociativo en JS?

Tags: javascript, array

buenas.
Estoy trabajando un pequeño programa en JS que utiliza arreglos "de objetos" o asociativos (¿cómo se les dice en JS? xd), de una forma algo así:

```
var datos = {
    data1: function(){return "algo"},
    data2: "Otra cosa",
    data3: function(){return "algo más"}
}
```

Bien. Si deseo recorrer dicho arreglo, de esta forma:

```
for(var i in datos) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Este código imprimiría esto:

> data1
>
> data2
>
> data3

Pero aquí viene mi duda, ¿de qué manera puedo "cambiar la posición" de algún elemento de este arreglo, para que se recorra en el orden que yo desee? Algo como

> data2
>
> data3
>
> data1

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: La pregunta respectiva sería , ¿En qué orden desea ? , dependerá exclusivamente de eso para un posible código de intercambio.

Comment: Cualquier orden, dependerá del usuario que maneje la aplicación. Por ejemplo, si tuviera un arreglo {a,b,c,d,e}, poder cambiar de posición d y b, y e con a, para resultar en {e, d, c, b, a}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `Object.keys` aqui la ref https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

El cual te ayuda a convertir tu JSON en ARREGLO, ya luego puedes obtener con el indice que quieras, para este caso seria el indice ramdomico.

```js
var datos = {
  data1: function() {
    return "algo"
  },
  data2: "Otra cosa",
  data3: function() {
    return "algo más"
  }
}


for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(datos).length; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(datos).length)
  console.log(Object.keys(datos)[x]);
}
```

> ```
> ahora sobre tu pregunta 
>
> Bien. Si deseo recorrer dicho arreglo, de esta forma:
>
> for(var i in datos) {
>     console.log(i);
> }
> ```

**Respuesta:**

El `forEach` que usas esta ligado directamente con los elementos, lo mejor seria usar el `for` tradicional para acceder a los elementos mediante los indices.

Answer (score 3):

Tengo un codigo que uso para cambiar la posicion de los elementos de un array.

```
var contenido = ['papa','mama','doctor']; //ingresamos el contenido

contenido.sort(f_randomico); //mezclamos el array
alert(contenido); //impresion de array

function f_randomico(a, b) { //funcion para mezclar el contenido
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Saludos Cordiales

George.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Mi duda principalmente era acerca de mover índices de arreglos *asociativos*, la cual pude solucionar gracias al usuario @x-rw.